# Why can't we search string vacua by computer?

Tags: string-theory, computer, string-theory-landscape

I am imagining this:

A database of Calabi-Yau manifolds. More can be added when more are found.

The software picks a random CY manifold, assigns random fluxes etc. It looks at the low energy sector which would correspond to some Supergravity action.
Solves various eigenvalues for masses and other constants.

Repeat.

If the results are 'interesting' by some set of criteria, store the results. Criteria might be: A nice ratio of lepton masses. Contains SU(3) gauge group for quarks. Small cosmological constant. Small Higgs mass. Things of that nature.

Could also use deep learning to suggest configurations based on past results. The software could be run on people's home PCs.

Obviously this will never go through all $10^{272000}$ or whatever vacua but it may pick out some interesting vacua and humans (or AI's) may be able to spot patterns.

I assume people have thought of doing this so I'm wondering what the bottleneck is? What is the bit that is difficult?

We do know at least some CY manifolds. So I assume the bottleneck is in computing the masses of the particles. I don't see what theoretically this would be difficult. As first we solve the Higg's potential $V(\phi)$ which is a simple polynomial equation which would split the gauge group in a certain way. Then we can find the particle masses and mixing matrices by diagonalising the mass matrix such as $\overline{\psi}_a M^{ab} \psi_b$. All these things can be automated. (Would we have to find renormalised masses? Or could we ignore this?)

I mean, I say it should be 'simple' but I couldn't do it! So I'm wondering what is the problem: is it theoertical, technical or physical (as in it would take too much effort!). Or is there no physicist alive would have the expertise to do such a thing?

**Edit**

I take it back. It seems there are lots of software that attempt to do similar things! But I haven't really seen any large scale roll out of such software to do this *automatically*.

Perhaps all the separate pieces of software have been built they just haven't all been put together in one system.

Comment: Update: I have found this interesting paper on the topic: https://s3.cern.ch/inspire-prod-files-5/5e4dcf32777a7fb8b6304e9ef9c1bf68

Comment: It seems to suggest that one has to solve systems of polynomial equations for the Higgs potential. And to avoid overcounting the solutions, one has to do NP-hard calculations. Interesting.

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong; computer-aided analysis of specific kinds of string vacua is a regular method of string phenomenology, for references search for "computer scan" e.g. [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string+phenomenology).

Comment: Surely the string theory landscape of possible CY manifolds is so enormously vast that picking a random point in it - or even $10^{100}$ random points - is unlikely to yield anything interesting.

Comment: @ACuriousMind True, though the question was more about automatically scanning over thousands of vaccua and storing the results automatically in central databases. Thanks for the link. My premise may be slightly wrong I admit.

Comment: @gandalf61 Well that depends on what percent are 'interesting'. Perhaps 0.01% are 'interesting' then it is worth doing. Nobody knows at present what percent are 'interesting' by any criteria. This is why we need computers to find out! Also you are assuming all the points are unrelated. Once we find one interesting point it may lead to more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google "machine learning string theory" and you will see it is now quite routine to search small sections of the landscape in this way.

However, at present particle masses within a given vacuum cannot be calculated with precision. There are quantitative reasons for this - e.g. the masses depend on the vevs of geometric moduli that are extremely hard to calculate - and qualitative - e.g. it's easy to miss crucial interaction terms that contribute to the outcome.